# require.js: Access all loaded modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs, js-amd

Is there any way to access all loaded modules of require.js?

Background:
I want to automatically call an `init()` function of my javascript-modules after all of them are loaded, see [require.js + backbone.js: How to structure modules that have an initialize function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740567/)
Without require.js I looped over my own module-storage and called each `init()` function.
I now want to do this with require.js. I'm aware that calling a `my_custom_init_function_favoritecolor_petname_love123` of every loaded module (including external libraries) is dangerous. I hope that this will cause less trouble than manually keeping a list of all modules (and the requirements of these modules) up-to-date. Forgetting one module init() is much more likely than a third-party library having my custom function name (though the latter is probably harder to debug).

Or does anyone have a better idea of how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Yes, `require.s.contexts._.defined` is an object which its keys are the module names and the values include the value returned from that module.

`require.s.contexts._.defined` includes all the modules (either `define()` or `require()` such as the Javascript file that is the starting point of the program and is indicated using `data-main` for RequireJS).

Comment: What is the difference between registry and defined on the context?  

I see a new object on the context._.registry object after a define('Mod',...), but not on context._.defined.  

After a require(['Mod'],...) call I see the module on context._.defined.

Comment: Cannot read property 'contexts' of undefined.  Require is the method, so switching to this worked for me 
requirejs.s.contexts._.defined

Answer (score 11):

Just finished a similar behavior within my RequireJS project. `require.s.contexts['_'].registry` holds the list of the registered modules.

I am using `Underscore.js` for getting, filtering and iterating the list of modules. Maybe the following code fragment helps you:

```
var modules_registered = _.keys(require.s.contexts['_'].registry);
var modules_to_be_initialized = _.filter(modules_registered, function(module_title) {
    return module_title.indexOf('modules') > -1;
});

_.each(modules_to_be_initialized, function(module_name) {
    require([module_name], function(current_module) {
        current_module.init();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm lazy, so I just did this:

```
    var modulesToLoad = Object.keys(require.s.contexts['_'].registry);
    require(modulesToLoad);
```

Based on other answers here.