# Make RequireJS place class on script tags it creates?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I've noticed that RequireJS creates script tags in the  tag as it loads modules.

Is there anyway to configure RequireJS to "tag" those elements w/ a class or an attribute of some kind that I could later target w/ jQuery later on?

e.g.:

```
var $requireJsScripts = $('script.require-script');
```

--UPDATE--

Ok.. I think I can get by on this little workaround for now.  Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19043564/282250) for the breadcrumb on `require.s.contexts._.defined`.  I'd still like to hear if anyone knows of a way to configure RequireJS to do something similar to what was laid out in the original question...

```
var loadedRjsModules = Object.keys(require.s.contexts._.defined);
var $scripts = $('script');
$scripts.each(function () {
    if ($(this).data('requiremodule') && $.inArray($(this).data('requiremodule'), loadedRjsModules)) {
        console.log(this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code, I don't see how RequireJS would allow adding anything custom to the script nodes at creation. The [routine](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/blob/3333465c2b6753e76f7d3b0e9362ca131a13cc36/require.js#L1810) that creates them has no provision for it. The [code](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/blob/3333465c2b6753e76f7d3b0e9362ca131a13cc36/require.js#L1834) that fleshes them out upon creation does not support it either.

There's an [onResourceLoad hook](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Internal-API%3a-onResourceLoad) considered part of the internal API. It could be used with the code you've put in your question instead of relying on `require.s.contexts._.defined`, which as far as I know is fully private and subject to change without notice.

Comment: So just do a loadedRjsModules.push() inside of the onResourceLoad event... but the documentation says that this method is "private" and "subject to change" as well...  arg.. I'm amazed RJS doesn't give any way to solve this..