# RequireJS extract list of all modules

Tags: module, requirejs, dependencies

How can one extract a list of all modules from a project using RequireJS? I am interested in getting the structure of the project, looking at modules and their dependencies.

Comment: Maybe this link will help you : 

[require.js: Access all loaded modules][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756483/require-js-access-all-loaded-modules

Comment: Can you please be more elaborate in what do u exactly mean when you say"structure of the project". Do u want to get dependency graph of modules?

Comment: liorlis thanks, I found an automated way to do that (see answer).
@Vishwanath yes. By structure of project I meant module dependencies in order to plot them in a graph. See answer for more details on how it is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an NPM package called [Madge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge) that can do exactly that. You can extract your RequireJS module dependencies and graph them using [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).