# Access modules in current scope

Tags: javascript, requirejs

This question describes how to fetch *all* loaded modules by requirejs: [require.js: Access all loaded modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756483/require-js-access-all-loaded-modules)

Is there any way to only fetch the required modules in the current scope? I.e. `foo` and `bar` below:

```
define(['foo', 'bar'], function(ko) {
    var allDefinedModules = require.s.contexts._.defined;
    // how to fetch only foo and bar?
});
```

I know that I can filter the list with a hard coded check for the two modules, but I want to know if there's a better way.

Comment: "foo" & "bar" are parameters of your function ("foo" is actually aliased `ko` in this code).

Comment: @Amit The difference is that `require.s.contexts._.defined` provides me with an object with keys equal to the string in the array, while `arguments` would just provide me with an array of the module values.